# Find the exact time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A teacher leaves his home everyday at 8:00A.M to come to school. If he comes 95 meters per minute. He will arrive one minute late for his class. If he walks 105 meters per minute he will arrive one minute early for his class. At what speed should he walk to arrive perfectly on time?

Is this the correct way to approach the problem...
D=95(t+1),D=105(t-1) if then, 95(t+1)=105(t-1)....t=20 then just substitute the found value of t to one of the equations to find the value of d then use the basic formula distance over time to find the solution...
doesn't the unit meters per minute cause problem at all

Comment: Well, what solution (for $D,t$) do you get this way?  Not sure about your unit question...of course, if you use $95,105$ then $D$ is measured in meters and $t$ is measured in minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No the units of speed won't cause any issue as when you are writing $D = Speed  . Time $ the unit of time is in minute and that of speed is in $metre \space  minute^{-1}$.Muĺtiplication of the two physical quantities gives unit of distance.Hence no issue.

Comment: thanks for clearing up the confusion but still will the steps I took lead to the solution or not?

Comment: Ya your logic is fine and no issue with it.Kindly approve the ans if you find it useful.

Comment: ok mate........